# First Order Logic: How to transform to prenex conjunctive normal form and Skolem form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, conjunctive-normal-form

This is the sentence that needs to be transformed: ∃x∀y(Ax → (Bxy ∨ ¬Cy)) → ∀x∃y(Py → Qyx)
I have gotten to the point where I eliminated all occurrences of → and imported all negations inside all other logical connectives. Which lead me here:

∃x∀y(Ax ∧ ¬Bxy ∧ Cy) ∨ ∀x∃y(Py ∧¬ Qyx)

But I can't seem to pull the quantifiers in front.

Comment: you forgot to negate the quantifiers, after eliminated all $\to$, you should have \begin{align}
&∃x∀y(Ax\to(Bxy\lor¬Cy)) \to ∀x∃y(Py \to Qyx)\\
=&\forall x\exists y(Ax\land\neg Bxy\land Cy)\lor\forall x\exists y(\neg Py \lor Qyx)\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't seem to pull the quantifiers in front.

To pull out the quantifiers, we will need to apply some quantifier distributive laws such that
$$∀x(Px)∨∀x(Q)↔∀x(Px∨Q)\tag{1}$$
$$∃y(Py)∨∃y(Qy)↔∃y(Py∨Qy)\tag{2}$$
Then we start from
\begin{align}
&\forall x\exists y(Ax\land\neg Bxy\land Cy)\lor\forall x\exists y(\neg Py \lor Qyx)\\
=&\forall x_1\forall x_2(\exists y(Ax_1\land\neg Bx_1y\land Cy)\lor\exists y(\neg Py \lor Qyx_2))\tag*{By $(1)$}\\
=&\forall x_1\forall x_2\exists y((Ax_1\land\neg Bx_1y\land Cy)\lor(\neg Py \lor Qyx_2))\tag*{By $(2)$}\\
\end{align}
Now you can put them into conjunctive normal form.

---

Note : As @user400188 mentioned, to avoid unnecessary confusion, we could just replace $(1)$ with
$$\forall x_1(Px_1)\lor\forall x_2(Qx_2)\leftrightarrow \forall x_1\forall x_2(Px_1\lor Qx_2)$$ or equivalently we can also apply the original $(1)$ twice.

Comment: Is $(1)$ meant to be missing an $x$ in $Qx$? If it isn't, then $(1)$ is correct but not the rule you used between line 1 & 2 of the second paragraph, and if it is, then it should be an implication not a biconditional.

Comment: @user400188 yes, it's just $Q$, like you mentioned, otherwise it won't hold, and i see the confusion, this is becuase two $x$ are in different  scope of quantifiers, in another words they are not the same $x$, and in that step we applied $(1)$ twice $\dots$

Comment: I believe if we write it in the following way, this confusion might gone \begin{align}
&\forall \color{red}{x_1}\exists y(A\color{red}{x_1}\land\neg B\color{red}{x_1}y\land Cy)\lor\forall \color{blue}{x_2}\exists y(\neg Py \lor Qy\color{blue}{x_2})\\
=&\forall \color{red}{x_1}\forall \color{blue}{x_2}(\exists y(A\color{red}{x_1}\land\neg B\color{red}{x_1}y\land Cy)\lor\exists y(\neg Py \lor Qy\color{blue}{x_2}))\tag*{By $(1)$}\\
\end{align} Thanks for the question $\overset{\cdot~\cdot}\smile$

Comment: Also note $\forall x(Q)\equiv Q$

Comment: What I meant was that a quantifier had been taken out using $\forall x(Px)\lor\forall x(Qx)\vdash \forall x(Px\lor Qx)$. However, the rule you state has a different logical form, because $Q$ does not depend on $x$ in it.

Comment: @user400188 Let's do this in two steps, would you agree if we apply $\forall x(Px)\lor Q\equiv\forall x(Px\lor Q)$ then
\begin{align}
&\forall\color{red}{x_1}\exists y(A\color{red}{x_1}\land\neg B\color{red}{x_1}y\land Cy)\lor\forall x_2\exists y(\neg Py \lor Qyx_2)\\
\equiv&\forall \color{red}{x_1}(\exists y(A\color{red}{x_1}\land\neg B\color{red}{x_1}y\land Cy)\lor\forall x_2\exists y(\neg Py \lor Qyx_2))
\end{align}

Comment: Also note $(∀x∃y(Ax∧¬Bxy∧Cy)∨∀x∃y(¬Py∨Qyx))\equiv(∀x_1∃y(Ax_1∧¬Bx_1y∧Cy)∨∀x_2∃y(¬Py∨Qyx_2))$

Comment: I understand what you did between steps $1$ and $2$, I just think that the quantifier distributive law should reflect them. That is, $(1)$ should be replaced with $\forall x(P(x))\lor\forall x(Q(x))\leftrightarrow \forall x_1(\forall x_2(P(x_1)\lor Q(x_2))$.

Comment: @user400188 Thanks for the suggestion, that's right, I just added some notes.

Comment: I see what you did now, $\forall x\exists y(\lnot Px\lor Qxy)$ does not depend on the same $x$ as $\forall x\exists y(Ax\land\lnot  Bxy\land Cy)$, and can then be treated as the $Q$ in your expression $(1)$. Sorry for my mistake, you do not actually need the note at the end.